# Serialized Java UI JSON Object to HTML Code

Tags: java, jquery, html, json, serialization

i need to connect to a WebService from which i get a JSON Object containing User Interface definitions. The only Problem is, that this Object contains definitions for Java UI's and i need to convert it.

It consists of several dropdowns and if the options of the dropdowns have childs in the hirarchy then it means that the childs should only be visible if the parent is selected.

So far so good. I dont get along Iterating throught the JSON, maybe it is to early in the morning. This is a example of part of the JSON:

```
{"inputConfigId":14580,"children":[{"inputConfigId":14581,"children":[{"inputConfigId":14582,"children":[{"inputConfigId":14583,"children":[{"inputConfigId":14584,"children":[{"inputConfigId":14585,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_HEADER","value":"Detail","sortOrder":0,"groupId":null}],"type":"LISTBOX_HEADER","value":"Thema","sortOrder":0,"groupId":null}],"type":"LISTBOX_HEADER","value":"Bereich","sortOrder":0,"groupId":null}],"type":"LISTBOX_HEADER","value":"Kontaktgrund","sortOrder":0,"groupId":null},{"inputConfigId":14586,"children":[{"inputConfigId":14587,"children":[{"inputConfigId":14588,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"Anfrage Shop","sortOrder":0,"groupId":null},{"inputConfigId":14589,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"Homepage","sortOrder":1,"groupId":null},{"inputConfigId":14590,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"Öffnungszeiten","sortOrder":2,"groupId":null},{"inputConfigId":14591,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"Postanschrift","sortOrder":3,"groupId":null},{"inputConfigId":14592,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"Rückfrage zu Outbound","sortOrder":4,"groupId":null},{"inputConfigId":14593,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"schriftl. Bestätigung","sortOrder":5,"groupId":null},{"inputConfigId":14594,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"Veranstaltungen","sortOrder":6,"groupId":null}],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"Allgemeine Anfragen","sortOrder":0,"groupId":null},{"inputConfigId":14595,"children":[{"inputConfigId":14596,"children":[{"inputConfigId":14597,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"AB entspricht nicht Auftrag","sortOrder":0,"groupId":null},{"inputConfigId":14598,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"AB fehlt Info","sortOrder":1,"groupId":null},{"inputConfigId":14599,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"AB ohne Preis","sortOrder":2,"groupId":null},{"inputConfigId":14600,"children":[],"type":"LISTBOX_ELEMENT","value":"Nicht eingegangen","sortOrder":3,"groupId":null}],
```

I now tried to build an Object to associate several Object types to html tags but don't now how to resume. Here is my Code:

```
 let elHtml = {
    "LAYOUT":{
      type: 'div',
      class: 'col-md-12'
    },
    "LISTBOX_ROW":{
      type: 'div',
      class: 'row'
    },
    "LISTBOX_ELEMENT":{
      type: 'option',
      class: 'form-control'
    },
    "BUTTON_ROW":{
      type: 'div',
      class: 'form-control'
    },
    "INPUTFIELD_ROW":{
      type: 'div',
      class: 'form-control'
    },
     "INPUTFIELDAREA_ROW":{
      type: 'div',
      class: 'form-control'
    },
    "INPUTFIELD":{
      type: 'textarea',
      class: 'form-control'
    }
  }
  let html = '';
  let exDD = [];
  if (typeof kgeObject.children != 'undefined') {
    for (let el of kgeObject.children) {
      if (el.type == "LISTBOX_ROW") {
        html += '<h2>' + el.value + '</h2>';
        if (el.children.length > 0) {
          html += '<select>';
          for (let child of el.children) {
            if(child.type == "LISTBOX_ELEMENT") html += '<option>'+child.value+'</option>';
            if(child.children.length > 0 ){
              let tempHTML = '<select data-showIf='+child.inputConfigId+child.value+'>';
              for(let sChild of child.children){
                if(child.type == "LISTBOX_ELEMENT") tempHTML += '<option>'+sChild.value + '</option>';
              }
              tempHTML += '</select>';
              exDD.push(tempHTML);
            }
          }
          html += '</select>';
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for(let exHtml of exDD){
    html += exHtml;
  }
  return html;
```

I hope someone could help me or give me any advice.
Thanks :)

Comment: The question is actually a bit ambigous. can you explain more ?

Comment: I need to generate HTML Input Elements out of the JSON. There should be Rows including one dropdown. If you select one option then depending on the JSON another dropdown will be shown.